# Does the rain affect any troops, buildings, or spells?

Tags: clash-royale

If you notice carefully, when overtime starts (and the battle is in Jungle Arena aka Arena 9), there are three quick flashes (signalling thunder/lightning) and a little later, it starts raining. The rain isn't easy to see but can be seen if viewed at the top right corner of the screen. This is the first time there has been a special effect for overtime in any arena.

So my question is, is the rain just there for show and realism of what happens in a jungle or does it affect any stats (i.e speed of troops, health, DPS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rain does not have any affect on gameplay, it's just a visual effect. If it did have an effect on troops, then there would be a change in overtime strategy, fundamentally changing the game in that arena. If it affected troops, it would have been in previous arenas.